# How to add 802.11ac adapter for 5 GHz WiFi (RTL8811AU )

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, usb, realtek-wireless

Plugging in a Dual-Band WiFi adapter with the Realtek RTL8811AU chipset does nothing visible and it does not show up in `ifconfig` even after a reboot.

Clearly the drivers must be installed separately.

--> I previously verified the precise model of adapter in Device Manager on a Win7 system using the same adapter.  This is important because there are several types of RTL8811 chips.

The driver disk has a directory of Linux files on it that I do not recognize as working with Ubuntu.

Google leads here:

[Ubuntu 16.04 8811AU Wireless driver](https://medium.com/@at15/ubuntu-16-04-8811au-wireless-driver-d29d6929a50c) (Medium.com)

which says to do this (paraphrased):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git
git clone https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux.git
(Enter username and password for Github)
cd rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8812au
```

and all seems to work until that final command, where I get the error message

> modprobe: FATAL: Module 8812au not found in directory /lib/modules/4.13.0-38-generic

None of the 5 GHz networks show up in the "up/down" WiFi settings.

Question:  **How to add RTL8811AU 802.11ac adapter for 5 GHz High-Speed WiFi**

Comment: TNX for the suggestion.  Just rebooted then retried the `sudo modprobe 8812au` and got the same response.  Went to `/lib/modules/4.13.0-38-generic` and it definitely is not there.  So did a `find . "88*"` and also a `find . "*88*"`and it did not find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the last command is not necessary and gives an error message with no meaning.

In Ubuntu 16.04 the driver gets installed into two places:

```
/sys/bus/usb//drivers/rtl8812au
/sys/module/rtl8812au
```

And it automatically loads after a reboot.

**When the `ifconfig` command is issued, it can clearly be seen operating as `wlx00e0xxxxxxxx` - reflecting the HWaddr in the name of the new interface.**

Then by clicking on the "up/down" icon at the upper right of the screen the 5 GHz networks are clearly visible in the first part of the WiFi Networks() section.

To recap, the commands necessary are simply these:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git
git clone https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux.git
(Enter username and password for Github)
cd rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux
make
sudo make install
(REBOOT)
```

**Then voila, it works.**

---

Note that when plugged into a USB 2.0 port, the speed will be limited to 433 Mbps.

---

Comment: Thank you for sharing! I'm curious if 5Ghz wifi works for you and if so, is it a unique SSID for the 5Ghz network? I've read there are issues with this driver/hardware trying to connect if a 2.4Ghz network uses the same SSID as a 5Ghz network (something that should work fine). Sources: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07FGX8LBF/ https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/issues/38